# Scrapyd jobid value inside spider

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

Framework Scrapy - Scrapyd server.

I have some problem with getting jobid value inside the spider.

After post data to http://localhost:6800/schedule.json the response is

```
status = ok
jobid = bc2096406b3011e1a2d0005056c00008
```

But I need use this jobid inside the current spider during the process. It can be used for open {jobid}.log file or other dynamic reasons.

```
class SomeSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "some"
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/"]
    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        for val in values:
            item = SomeItem()
            item['jobid'] = self.jobid # ???!
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

But I see this jobid only after the task is finihed :( Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess there is an easier way, but you can extract job id from command line args. IIRC, scrapyd launches a spider giving it a jobid in parameters. Just explore `sys.args` where you need jobid.

Comment: All genius is easy ;) Thanks, mate!

Some example:

`if (len(sys.argv)>2): 
     if ('_job' in sys.argv[3]): 
         self.jobid = sys.argv[3].rsplit('=')`

Comment: @Maxim, glad it worked. Please, don't forget to accept and upvote answers that worked for you.

Comment: It requeres 15 points of reputation. I'll back to this post after some growth ;) Thank you.

Comment: You can also get it from the `SCRAPY_JOB` environment variable: `os.environ['SCRAPY_JOB']`

Comment: @PabloHoffman what happens if we have multiple schedules running? I get the jobids but I am not sure if they will be correct every time.

Comment: This is now os.environ['SHUB_JOBKEY']

Answer (score 10):

You can get it from the `SCRAPY_JOB` *environment variable*:

```
os.environ['SCRAPY_JOB']
```

Comment: This is now `os.environ['SHUB_JOBKEY']`

Answer (score 1):

In the spider.py -->

```
class SomeSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "some"
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.jobid = kwargs.get('_job')

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        for val in values:
           item = SomeItem()
           item['jobid'] = self.jobid # ???!
           items.append(item)
        return items
```